# Is it possible to open immediately Dropbox or GoogleDrive in UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios8, dropbox, icloud

I need to make a custom menu instead of UIDocumentMenuViewController with buttons: iCloud, Dropbox and Google Drive.

And is it possible to open immediately Dropbox or GoogleDrive (by default iCloudDrive will be open) in UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Answer (score 1):

you should use UIDocumentMenuViewController, like

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *menus = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.image"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
menus.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:menus animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and in this menu, user can choose iCloud, google drive, dropbox ...etc
you show handle UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UIDocumentMenuDelegate to show the picker and do something

For example

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
     // do something
    }
}
- (void)documentMenu:(UIDocumentMenuViewController *)documentMenu didPickDocumentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)documentPicker {
    documentPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Note.
User need install google drive or dropbox app and then drive menu can be seen.

poor english, wish  you can understand.